# Which lipoprotein has the highest protein content?

Tags: nutrition, proteins, lipids

I know that HDLs have the highest protein/lipid ratio but know that the HDLs are very small molecules too and I couldn’t find the exact answer for this question. I mean, by amounts which of these lipoproteins have the most protein?

Comment: Please do not use the title of a question in lieu of the question itself. You need to carefully define numerically your concept of “highest protein content” and explain how it differs from protein/lipid ratio. At the moment it is completely unclear, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

LDL has the higher protein content than HDL. LDL consists of Apo B48 and Apo B100. These are proteins with higher molecular weights between 250 kDa to 550 kDa as compared to other apoproteins. And these apoproteins are not present in HDL.

And if lipoprotein (a) is included in comparison then it has highest protein content.

(Via:  https://lipidmaps.org/resources/lipidweb/index.php?page=lipids/simple/lipoprot/index.htm)